# Is there a way to have a custom death message in vanilla Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Basically, I want a custom death message by using `tellraw`, but how would I make it detect someone has died? Do I use a scoreboard system, do I use `testfor`, what do I use to make it detect someone died?

Comment: It is not... I want it to show a custom death message when someones dies, not when someone is a victor...

Comment: You've been asking a lot of questions recently, and they haven't really been getting a good reception.  That's because you've displayed no effort in trying to solve this yourself.  While that's not a requirement to ask a question here, you'll get a much better reception (and much better answers), if you show us what you've tried.  Just saying you don't know how doesn't do much for us, I'm afraid.

Comment: I tryed to make my own system, but it just looks ugly in general, with the book and quills, and was wondering if there's another way to do this, that's why I asked you guys here.

Comment: @MinecraftDoge Next time you ask a question, please check for any related questions or possible duplicates before asking. You can see a  dropdown menu after you typed in the title, containing some maybe-related questions which you can (and I recommend you do) check for duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

fist you'll need a score board for death count

```
/scoreboard objectives add <score name> deathCount
```

when its greater then one, use `tellraw @a[score_<score name>_min=1] "you died"` to give the message to the person that died

then you'll want to reset all of the death scores to zero so you don't give the message more then once to a player

```
/scoreboard players set @a <score name> 0
```

EDIT: made it a little more of a tutorial for people finding this thread

Comment: Could you explain a little more?  Such as what scoreboard items s/he would need, and etc.

Comment: It's fine, I found out myself, but I can't put an answer, but I kinda used the scoreboard objectives like Venya explains me here, anyways, thanks for the answer :)